# Is it possible to select questions by two or more tags at once?

Tags: support, questions, tags

For example: reseach-level + particle-physics + quantum-field-theory

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can search for " [research-level] [particle-physics] [quantum-field-theory] ".

Here's an example:
[[particle-physics] [quantum-mechanics]](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/particle-physics+quantum-mechanics)